# How do I calculate the bounding box for an ortho matrix for Cascaded shadow mapping?

Tags: opengl, c++, shadow-mapping, glm

I've been trying to get a cascaded shadow mapping system implemented on my engine, though it appears to be that the bounding boxes for the cascades aren't correct.

The part I'm interested in can be found [here](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial49/tutorial49.html), under the function name "CalcOrthoProjs".

I've been trying to understand the matrix multiplications with [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/73851/how-do-i-fit-the-camera-frustum-inside-directional-light-space) answer, and the ogldev variable and function names are kind of confusing me.

This is how I modified ogldev's function to work with my variables:

```
void Scene::calcOrthoProjections(Camera &camera, glm::mat4 LightView, std::vector<glm::mat4> &orthoContainer, std::vector<GLfloat> &cascadeEnd) {
GLfloat FOV, nearPlane, farPlane, ratio;
camera.getPerspectiveInfo(FOV, nearPlane, farPlane);
ratio = static_cast<GLfloat>(RE::config.height) / static_cast<GLfloat>(RE::config.width);

GLfloat tanHalfHFov = glm::tan(glm::radians(FOV / 2.0f));
GLfloat tanHalfVFov = glm::tan(glm::radians((FOV*ratio) / 2.0));


for (GLuint i = 0; i < NR_CASCADES; i++) {
    GLfloat xn = cascadeEnd[i]     * tanHalfHFov;
    GLfloat xf = cascadeEnd[i + 1] * tanHalfHFov;
    GLfloat yn = cascadeEnd[i]     * tanHalfVFov;
    GLfloat yf = cascadeEnd[i + 1] * tanHalfVFov;

    //The frustum Corners on View(Camera) space
    glm::vec4 frustumCorners[8]{
        //Near Face
        glm::vec4( xn,  yn, cascadeEnd[i], 1.0),
        glm::vec4(-xn,  yn, cascadeEnd[i], 1.0),
        glm::vec4( xn, -yn, cascadeEnd[i], 1.0),
        glm::vec4(-xn, -yn, cascadeEnd[i], 1.0),
        //Far face
        glm::vec4( xf,  yf, cascadeEnd[i + 1], 1.0),
        glm::vec4(-xf,  yf, cascadeEnd[i + 1], 1.0),
        glm::vec4( xf, -yf, cascadeEnd[i + 1], 1.0),
        glm::vec4(-xf, -yf, cascadeEnd[i + 1], 1.0),

        
    };

    //The frustum Corners in LightSpace
    glm::vec4 frustumCornersL[8];

    GLfloat minX, maxX, minY, maxY, minZ, maxZ;
    minX = minY = minZ = std::numeric_limits<GLfloat>::max();
    maxX = maxY = maxZ = std::numeric_limits<GLfloat>::min();

    glm::mat4 cam = (camera.getProjection() * camera.getView());
    glm::mat4 camInverse = glm::inverse(cam);
    
    for (GLuint j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        //View(Camera) space to world space
        glm::vec4 vW = camInverse * frustumCorners[j];
        //world space to light space
        frustumCornersL[j] = LightView * vW;

        minX = min(minX, frustumCornersL[j].x);
        maxX = max(maxX, frustumCornersL[j].x);
        minY = min(minY, frustumCornersL[j].y);
        maxY = max(maxY, frustumCornersL[j].y);
        minZ = min(minZ, frustumCornersL[j].z);
        maxZ = max(maxZ, frustumCornersL[j].z);
    }
    orthoContainer[i] = glm::ortho(minX, maxX, minY, maxY, minZ, maxZ) * LightView;
 }
}
```

LightView represents a matrix created with:

```
glm::LookAt(-glm::normalize(light.direction), glm::vec3(0.0), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0))
```

camera.getProjection() returns the perspective matrix of the main camera

camera.getView() returns a LookAt at the objective the camera is looking at

The orthoContainer values are then fed into the depth rendering unaltered afterwards (by anything other than the model matrix of each model)

I wrote some comments on how I think the math is done, trying to understand what's wrong.

The result is a frustum too wide, resulting on low res shadows(even for the closest shadow map):
[image: Low res shadows]

and this is the depth map of the closest shadow map:
[image: Depth buffer of the closest shadow map]

any insight as to why this isn't working, or any other best practice advice, is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the calculation of the frustum corners in ogldev tutorial is a bit confusing and I think I've found some issues with their code:

1. Usually the camera fov specifies the vertical fov (this is also true for their tutorial regarding perspective projection), but as the calculation suggest the fov is assumed to be the horizontal fov. This means that tanHalfVFov should be just the tan and tanHalfHFov should be multiplied by ratio
2. The multiplication by ratio should happen after performing the tan.
3. Since ratio equals height / width, I think you should divide by ratio

To summarize, I think the calculation of tanHalfVFov and tanHalfHFov should be:

```
GLfloat tanHalfHFov = glm::tan(glm::radians(FOV / 2.0f)) / ratio;
GLfloat tanHalfVFov = glm::tan(glm::radians(FOV / 2.0));
```

Also, in your calculation of the world space position of each frustum corner, since the corners are in view space, in order to transform to world space you need to multiply by the inverse view matrix. So cam in your code above should just be the view matrix:

```
glm::mat4 cam = camera.getView();
```

Comment: Quite a good response. I really appreciate it. After many tries and a lot of time spent trying to figure it out, I got nowhere and had to leave it because of other responsabilities. It's a good improvement, and I can't be thankful enough.

So sorry for a response this late, but it's only now that I could get back on to programming. Again, thank you so much!